# Eclipse/wxWidgets - Cleaning leads to many errors

Tags: c++, eclipse, wxwidgets, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to set up my first app using eclipse and wxwidgets on Mac.
I followed the [wxwidgets guide](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Creating_CDT_projects_for_wxWidgets_applications) and set up everything correctly.

I copied the [HelloWorld.cpp](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_helloworld.html) to the project and built it. (Building was successful and I even get a .app file. But opening it says: Can't open it because it is damaged or uncomplete.

When I clean my project I get 33 error messages as:

- Function "somefunction" could not be resolved
- Invalid arguments '
- Method "somemethod" could not be resolved
- Type "sometype" could not be resolved

Did I forget to set up something?

Comment: It looks like you have a header file that contains declarations of "somefunction" and "somemethod" but in your cpp file you dont have definitions. Also please go to Project-->C++ Index and run rebuild.

Comment: @chickenduy, also make sure that if you build shared version (AKA DLL build), you copy the dylib to the folder where the executable is. BTW, why do you use Eclipse? Xcode is a free download...